# How to handle logs when deploying via war files

Tags: moqui

When I deploy moqui in tomcat6 by dropping in a war file, I get:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /log/moqui.log (Permission denied)

Same with error.log.
I start tomcat with: sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 start

Is that where the log files should go in the production mode, and, if so, why is it getting this error? Or is there a change that I need make in configuration?

The app still runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These errors were caused by a bug in the code because the moqui.runtime system env var had not been set when the Logger was initialized. That is fixed in the master branch in commit #a6cc299.